# My custom semaphore doesn't seem to work in my program

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore, synchronize

Basically I have a method that I want to synchronize (only let one thread in at a time), however I'm not allowed to use the synchronized keyword for this particular practice. Instead, I decided to create a semaphore and just set the value to 1, therefore acting like a mutually exclusive lock (which is what I believe the synchronized keyword does right?).

So basically, my Semaphore class looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Semaphore
  {
    private int count = 0;

    public Semaphore (int init_val) {
      count = init_val;
    }

    public synchronized void P() {
      count = count - 1;

      while(count < 0) {
        try {
          wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
    }

    public synchronized void V() {
      count = count + 1;
      notifyAll();
    }
   }
```

And I'm using it inside the method I want to synchronize like this (just an example):

```
Semaphore s = new semaphore(1);
int x = 0;

public void add() {
   s.P()
   int x = x + 1;
   System.out.println(x);
   s.V()
}
```

I have 100 threads calling the add method, but for some reason the value of x is concurrent, but not going up in order (race condition). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any advice?

Comment: *I'm not allowed to use the synchronized keyword* - **but** you are using it.

Comment: Also, it's running in the same thread, so `P` will block indefinitely. I also think your `while` condition should be changed so that it's comparing the `count` to the `init_val` ... because what would happen in `init_val` was `2`?

Comment: You are also shadowing the field with `int x = x + 1;`

Comment: I'm able to use synchronized inside my custom semaphore, just not outside of it.